# How to search and book fares with promotion code applied with sabre?

Tags: sabre

I use FareLLSRQ (FareRQ) and OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ (OTA_AirAvailRQ) to search flight tickets.
Now, the airline provides me a promotion code and I want to apply this code when searching and booking.

Is it feasible with Sabre?

Comment: What kind of promotion code? Is it like a corporate Fare or simmiliar?

Comment: Hi @Thomas, it is a.k.a Account Code (command WPAC).

Comment: <PricingQualifiers>
   <Account>
    <Code>ABC123</Code>
   </Account>
  </PricingQualifiers> or <PricingQualifiers>
   <Corporate>
    <ID>ABC12</ID>
   </Corporate>
  </PricingQualifiers> should do the trick then. Always depends how the airline is loading the fares into Sabre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hung,

The OTA_AirAvailRQ service only serves to search for flight availability between a city pair and it is not possible to use the informed commercial agreement.

The FareLLSRQ Using this API, you can perform a basic fare quote, specify preferred airlines, specify a currency code, specify to return base fare and tax information, specify an account code, specify a corporate ID, specify a fare basis code, specify a fare level, specify a global indicator, specify a fare basis code/ticket designator, and several other parameters.

Depending on the commercial agreement you can use:

- AccountCode: //*:FareRQ/*:OptionalQualifiers/*:PricingQualifiers/*:Account/*:Code="accountCode"
- CorporateId: //*:FareRQ/*:OptionalQualifiers/*:PricingQualifiers/*:Corporate/*:ID="CorporateID"

[image]